# Let $(X,Y)$ be a random vector. Show $P(x,y) > 0$ implies $P(y) >0$ and $\sum_y P(x,y) = P(x)$ for $X = x, Y = y$ using the axioms of probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $(X,Y)$ be a random vector.

How does one show $P(x,y) > 0$ implies $P(y) >0$ and $\sum_y P(x,y) = P(x)$ for $X = x, Y = y$ using 
the axioms of probability ?

(In the continuous case the $\sum$ should be substituted with $\int_Y$).

Intuitively this is true, since if $P(x) = 0$ then $(X=x,Y=y)$ cannot occur. Also the sum over all $Y=y$ for some $X = x$ should give the probability of $X=x$, since this probability of $X=x$ is split among the $y$'s ? **However how does one show that a distribution must follow these intuitively ideas**?

Comment: Hint: for the discrete case, $P\{Y = y\} = \sum_x P\{X = x, Y = y\}$ is just the axiom of countable additivity. The events $\{X = x_1, Y = y\}, \{X = x_2, Y = y\}, \cdots$ are _mutually exclusive_ (the occurrence of one excludes the occurrence of all the others) and their union is the event $\{Y = y\}$.  In short, prove the second part first.  For continuous random variables, the first result is false. $f_{X,Y}(x,y) > 0$ does not necessarily imply that $f_Y(y) > 0$ also.

Answer (score 1):

By the [Law of total probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability), you have that $$P(X=x)=\sum_{y}P(X=x|Y=y)P(Y=y)$$ Now using the formula for the conditional probability, i.e. that $$P(X|Y=y)=\frac{P(X=x,Y=y)}{P(Y=y)}$$ you can conclude that $$P(X=x)=\sum_{y}P(X=x,Y=y)$$ and by abusing notation $$P(x)=\sum_{y}P(x,y)$$

The intuition behind this is the same as in [Law of total probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability).

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary to drag in the notion of conditional probability to prove the result?

Comment: @DilipSarwate No, of course not. I found the conditional more intuitive than the intersection (X=x, Y=y).

Comment: As my comment on the main question suggests, the law of total probability (without the use of conditional probabilities) is just the countable additivity axiom, but perhaps countable additivity is not intuitive....

Comment: @DilipSarwate I do not insist, probably the OP does not like my answer neither, so I will delete it. Countable additivity is of course intuitive, but did not come to my mind.

Comment: Thank you tom7. So we sum over $y$ only when $P(Y=y) > 0$ and $P(X|Y=y)$ should be $P(X=x|Y=y)$ ? "The intuition behind this.." - We are using the Law of total Probability, so the intuition is of course the same as the Law of total Probability ?